# How to ignore DUPLICATE ENTRY error when updating multiple records at once using TypeORM

Tags: sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to update hundreds of database records using the TypeORM library. Problem is that sometimes DUPLICATE ERR is returned from SQL when the bulk upload is performed and stops the whole operation. Is possible to set up TypeORM in a way so duplicate entries are ignored and the insert is performed?
The table is using two primary keys:
[image]

This is my insert command (TypeORM + Nestjs):

```js
  public async saveBulk(historicalPrices: IHistoricalPrice[]) {
    if (!historicalPrices.length) {
      return;
    }
    const repoPrices = historicalPrices.map((p) => this.historicalPricesRepository.create(p));
    await this.historicalPricesRepository.save(repoPrices, { chunk: 200 });
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've never worked with `typeorm`, but it looks like they've had support for `onIgnore` since Q4 2018, at least based on this [pull request](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/2983/files#diff-f12ef5527b9bc2971ab7a8247c71dd735a43cd7a1c859bd206b61dee8c7f617d). That will treat duplicate inserts as warnings instead of causing error.

Comment: Thanks for your commentary. It points to correct solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use `InsertQueryBuilder` to save the entities instead of `repository.save` method. `InsertQueryBuilder` will allow you to call an additional method `orIgnore()` which will add `IGNORE` literal into your mysql `INSERT` statement. From mysql official doc:

> When INSERT IGNORE is used, the insert operation fails silently for rows containing the unmatched value, but inserts rows that are matched.

One demerit is obviously that you'll have to now chunk the rows on your own. `InsertQueryBuilder` doesn't provide any options to chunk the entities. Your code should look like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < historicalPrices.length; i += 200) {
  const chunk = historicalPrices.slice(i, i + 200);
  const targetEntity = this.historicalPricesRepository.target;
  await this.historicalPricesRepository
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(targetEntity)
    .values(chunk)
    .orIgnore()
    .execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. Chunking to code on my own is completely fine as it removes unnecessary layer of abstraction